# Writing to stack as local variable in _start function (x86 ASM)

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm writing a compiler - or something that looks like it - and I'm at the part where I generate simple, **unoptimized** assembly code.

The code works, except for one thing.

I understand that `%esb` and `%esp` work as follows in a function call:

```
Parameter #N       -> N*4+4(%ebp)
Parameter 2        -> 12(%ebp)
Parameter 1        -> 8(%ebp)
Return Address     -> 4(%ebp)
Old %ebp           -> (%ebp)
Local Variable 1   -> -4(%ebp)
Local Variable 2   -> -8(%ebp) and (%esp)
```

However, the code below, which is output from my compiler, segfaults on the first line where I try to assign to `-8(%esp)` in `_start`. Doing the same thing in the `twice` function does not segfault.

It seems to be that in the _start function I can't store 'local variables' on the stack, and I wonder how I should fix this?

The program:

```
.section .data
.section .text
.globl _start
.globl twice
.type twice, @function
twice:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp

    movl 8(%ebp), %eax
    movl 8(%ebp), %ebx
    addl %eax, %ebx
    movl %ebx, -4(%ebp)
    movl %ebx, %eax
    movl %eax, -8(%ebp)
    movl %eax, -8(%ebp)
end_twice:
    leave
    ret
_start:
    movl $10, %eax
    movl %eax, -8(%ebp)
    movl $10, %eax
    pushl %eax
    call twice
    addl $4, %esp
    movl %eax, -8(%ebp)
    movl %eax, %ebx
    # Exit stuff.
    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80
```

Original input:

```
int twice(int x)
{
    return x+x;
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    x = 10;
    x = multiply(x);
}
```

Comment: It's your job to initialize `ebp` if you want to use it. Notice you did `mov %esp, %ebp` in `twice` but you did no such thing in `_start`. Also it would be a good idea to actually allocate the space you try to use (normally done by `subl $size, %esp`).

Comment: coding out the equivalent of "enter" microcoded instruction (which is a good thing) suggests that you may want  to do the same with "leave" instruction too.

Comment: Initializing the %ebp pointer did the trick! Thank you for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd typically, if using EBP as pointer to local stack frame, not write to where it's pointing to before calling the sub. instead, you'd simply push to ESP, and leave it to the sub to set up EBP accordingly, so you can read from where you pushed to ESP before.  Your use of EBP, if using "traditional" stack frames, is therefore incorrect.

Comment: You are correct. So what I do now is simply push the values using 'pushl' instead of immediatly writing to the stack.